# How do I make div fill the remaining space?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have this basic html layout:

- Header
- Auto-sizing DIV
- Footer.

Header and footer have fixed pixel size.

```html
<div id="header">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>

<div id="auto">
  This div should automatically change size
</div>

<div id="footer">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

And the CSS

```css
document,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#auto {
  /* it fills 100% of the window height instead the remaining height*/
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

How do I make div fill the remaining space?

Comment: not sure what you're asking, can you be more clear?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, do you want the footer to always stick to the bottom of the page?

Comment: you're really going to need to try harder with this question if you dont want to get downvoted and flagged. code youve tried? errors? jsfiddle? anything...

Comment: You need to provide some code...

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for a [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but I myself use a sticky footer.

[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)
[StickyFooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

I'd advise you to create a container `div` element which contains the `header`, `main` and `footer` and set that with `width:100%; height:100% min-height:???;`

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it by getting the window height with jQuery and take the height of the header and footer of the windows height and set that on your div.

Like this:

```
header {
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
}

.resizable {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;    
    height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var newHeight = $(window).height() - 20;

    $(".resizable").css("height", newHeight);

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kvfjr/)

Comment: Good effort but that element you call resizable is not actually resizable. Have you tried to resize the page? :)

Comment: That's true but if you reload the page after resizing it should work fine. It's not the best solution but the only one I could come up with for now :)

Comment: Well if you put this inside `$(window).resize` function too, that works but i dont think OP wants a jquery solution.